# How does a HP Data Vault (using Windows Home Server) share a logical drive across multiple physical drives?

Tags: windows, partitioning, windows-server-2008, disk-space

I've recently procured a HP Data Vault, and have been looking at the partitions in Disk Management.

D: (a logical drive) links to two physical hard drives (each with a NTFS partition).

Total Disk Space: 1.3 TB
Free Space: 2.7 TB

Now, as far as I knew, a logical drive can only live in one physical disk, but I can see on the HP Data Vault that it isn't the case.

Is this some fancy HP magic, or is there some Windows-based partitioning strategy I don't know about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is how Windows Home Server has to be setup in order for Drive Extender to work. You want to be very cautious if you are in to this area of the server.  Changing any of this or even transfering files by not using the "Shared Folders" link on your desktop can mess up the system.

Spend some time here; www.wegotserved.com  it is a great site for WHS users